# Scroll view - positioning UI elements in "out of screen" pages

Tags: ios, interface-builder, scrollview

I'm writing an iPhone app where I need to scroll between 3 views of data.

I'm trying to use the scroll view but in Interface Builder I have some difficulties in placing UILAbels, Text Fieldsand the other UI elements of the second and third pages because I should put them "out of the screen bounds" availble in IB (I'm not sure if I have well described the problem).

Is there any easy way to place the UI elements, in IB, for the 2nd and 3rd page ?

Would it be better to use another approch, like for example having three View controllers and then use them in the Scroll view ?

Thanks,
Corrado

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what is "driving" the three views.  Will it always be three views?

If each page is a whole new screen then you could use the UIPageViewController.

This is a controller that manages a number of ViewControllers including swiping between the different view controllers.

Think of a horizontal UITableViewController but one that dispenses UIViewControllers instead of UITableViewCells.

Comment: Yes, each page is a whole new screen. I will check into the UIPageViewController. Thanks for the suggestion.